# SQL Server database backup to store only the last 7 backups in a file

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a scheduled task that will run (every night) a SQL script to fully backup my database X to a file. I want that file to store up to 7 full backups. The way I tried doing this is using the following code:

```
SELECT @SQL = '
BACKUP DATABASE [X] 
TO  DISK = N''\file.bak'' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N''name'', RETAINDAYS = 7
'
```

But this doesn't overwrite/delete full backups contained on that file that are older than seven days.

Any ideas? Suggestions for alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to study and implement  Ola Hallengren's [**SQL Server Backup solution**.](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) Its free and is widely tested and [recognized](https://ola.hallengren.com/organizations.html) in the community.

e.g :

Back up all user databases, using checksums and compression; verify the backup; and delete old backup files

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
@Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
@Directory = 'C:\Backup',
@BackupType = 'FULL',
@Verify = 'Y',
@Compress = 'Y',
@CheckSum = 'Y',
@CleanupTime = 24
```

[Automate and Improve Your Database Maintenance Using Ola Hallengren's Free Script](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automate-and-improve-your-database-maintenance-using-ola-hallengrens-free-script/) will give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The RETAINDAYS  option maps to the Backup set will expire in x days option in SSMS. See my previous answer on this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68643/what-is-the-use-of-backup-set-will-expire-option-while-creating-backup-databa/68663#68663)