# Backup set expire option - Backup SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, restore, maintenance-plans

I had seen an option while taking a backup i.e. set backup expire date, I have a doubt. What does this mean:

1. Backup will be no longer valid after date DD/MM/YYYY?
2. Backup declared with option, is it valid file to restore?
3. Can we store this backups for 1 year after expire date option is given and restore?
4. can Expired Backups(not deleted/purged) restored, any cons or limitations?

Any links to this concept also appreciated, which helps many junior DBA's.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Answered here by @JamesAnderson

The "Backup set will Expire" option is used to indicate how long a backup should be prohibited from being over written. It will not clean up old backup files. You can use the "Maintenance Clean up Task" in your maintenance plan to clean up backups files older than a certain number of days.

[What is the use of "Backup set will Expire:" option while creating Backup Database task in Maintenance plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68643/what-is-the-use-of-backup-set-will-expire-option-while-creating-backup-databa)

Comment: so i can use the backup to restore as valid file until i purge/delete permanently am i correct?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with being able to 'restore' the backup.  It's a protection mechanism to make sure that backup set cannot be overwritten by a new backup until that expiration date.

Comment: Yes, as @Scott Hodgin said, consider it an "Overwrite allow date" and not a "this backup will no longer restore" date.